# Use mapply or lapply to nested list

Tags: r, lapply, sampling, mapply

I want to apply a sample function to a nested list (I will call this list `bb`) and I also have a list of numbers (I will call this list `k`) to be supplied in the sample function. I would like each of the numbers in k to iterate through all the values of each list in bb. How to do this using `mapply` or `lapply`?

Here are the data:

```
k <- list(1,2,4,3) #this is the list of numbers to be supplied in the `sample.int` function
b1 <- list(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4),c(3,4,5),c(4,5,6)) #The first list of bb
b2 <- list(c(1,2),c(2,3),c(3,4),c(4,5), c(5,6)) #The second list of bb
bb <- list(b1,b2) #This is list bb containing b1 and b2 whose values are to be iterated through
```

I created this `mapply` function but it didn't get the expected outcome:

```
mapply(function(x, y) { 
   x[sample.int(y,y, replace = TRUE)] 
}, bb,k, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

This only returns 10 output values but I would like each number of k to loop through all values of the two lists in `bb` and so there should be 10*2 outputs for the two lists in `bb`. I might be using `mapply` in the wrong way and so I would appreciate if anyone can point me to the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outer` is your friend. It's normally used to calculate the outer matrix product. *Consider:*

```
outer(1:3, 2:4)
1:3 %o% 2:4  ## or
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    3    4
# [2,]    4    6    8
# [3,]    6    9   12
```

It also has a `FUN=` argument that defaults to `"*"`. However it enables you to calculate any function over the combinations of `x` and `y` *cross-wise*, i.e. `x[1] X y[1], x[1] X y[2], ...` whereas `*apply` functions only calculate `x[1] X y[1], x[2] X y[2], ...`. So let's do it:

```
FUN <- Vectorize(function(x, y) x[sample.int(y, y)])

set.seed(42)
res <- outer(bb, k, FUN)
res
#        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  
# [1,] List,1 List,2 List,4 List,3
# [2,] List,1 List,2 List,4 List,3
```

This result looks a little weird, but we may easily `unlist` it.

```
res <- unlist(res, recursive=F)
```

#### Result

```
res
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 2 3 4
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 2 3
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] 2 3 4
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] 4 5 6
# 
# [[9]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# [[10]]
# [1] 3 4 5
# 
# [[11]]
# [1] 3 4
# 
# [[12]]
# [1] 4 5
# 
# [[13]]
# [1] 2 3
# 
# [[14]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[15]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# [[16]]
# [1] 2 3 4
# 
# [[17]]
# [1] 3 4 5
# 
# [[18]]
# [1] 2 3
# 
# [[19]]
# [1] 3 4
# 
# [[20]]
# [1] 1 2
```

Voilà, 20 results.

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf. Indeed `outer` is a rarely sought but very useful function. Just like you said, the `mapply` function loops through both lists at the same time and so it does exhaust all elements, even when I tried this: `Map(function(i) mapply(function(x, y) { 
  x[sample.int(y,y, replace = TRUE)] 
}, bb,k, SIMPLIFY = FALSE), seq_along(bb))`